# Android Trouble With TextViews and Buttons

Tags: android, button, random, timer, textview

Okay so I am making a application just for fun that has a random number pop up on the screen. If you tap the button with the same number as the random number you get a point, and if you tap the button with the incorrect number, you lose a point. The catch is you only have 10 seconds to score enough points (I did not get to the part where i check if the user scored enough points to win). Anyway I have two main problems with the application. The timer will not display to the screen without the app crashing (I put a try/catch to stop it from crashing so I could work on other things) and when you tap the correct button, your score does not go up. However, if you tap the incorrect button, the score will go down. I find that to be very odd.

Thank you for your help!

Here is my Activity Class:

```
package ab.game.crazynumbers;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Level1Activity extends Activity {

Random r;
Timer t;
int random;
int time;
boolean running = false;
TextView showingnumber;
TextView score;
TextView timer;
Handler handler;
Button b1;
Button b2;
Button b3;
Button b4;
Button b5;
Button b6;
Button b7;
Button b8;
Button b9;
Button b0;
int playerscore;
TextView finalscore;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.level_1);

    playerscore = 0;

    showingnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_number);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_score);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_timer2);
    finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalscore);

    running = true;
    time = 10;

    b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_0);
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_1);
    b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_2);
    b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_3);
    b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_4);
    b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_5);
    b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_6);
    b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_7);
    b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_8);
    b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1_9);

    randomnumber();

    b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (1 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (1 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;

        }
    });

    b2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (2 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (2 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (3 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (3 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (4 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (4 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (5 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (5 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (6 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (6 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b7.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (7 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (7 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b8.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (8 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (8 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b9.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (9 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (9 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    b0.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {

            if (e.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                if (0 == random) {
                    playerscore++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }

                if (0 != random) {
                    playerscore--;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
                        }
                    });
                    randomnumber();
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    startTimer();

}

public void startTimer() {

    Timer t = new Timer("Game Timer");

    handler = new Handler();

    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (time > 0) {

                time -= 1;

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            timer.setText("Seconds Remaining: "+ time);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

            if (time <= 0) {
                this.cancel();
                  finish();
            }

        }

    },

    // time before start of timer
            0,

            // time before it runs again
            1000);

}

public void randomnumber() {

    r = new Random();
    random = r.nextInt(10);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            showingnumber.setText(String.valueOf(random));
        }
    });

}

}
```

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game_timer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Seconds Remaining: 0.0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/game_score"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Your Score Is 0"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_marginTop="73dp"
    android:text="4" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_timer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="89dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/game_number"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/game_score"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:text="7" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.5"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.8"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.0"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/b1.2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:text="0" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.6"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:text="6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.9"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.7"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.6"
    android:text="9" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1.3"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/b1.1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b1.6"
    android:text="3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout says **game_timer** and your code says **game_timer2**.

Check on that.
your lines are:

```
timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.game_timer2);
finalscore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalscore);
```

game_timer2 and finalscore Don't exists on your layout.

You should use a Handler to edit your GUI. For example.
In your class add this

```
 static final int SCORE_UP = 1;     static final int SCORE_DOWN = 2;

     final Handler mhandler = new Handler() { 
                  int playerscore = 0;
          @Override
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              switch(msg.what ){
              case SCORE_UP:
              {
                  playerscore++;
              }
                  break;
              case SCORE_DOWN:
              {
                  playerscore--;
              }
                  break;
                  default:

              }
              score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
             }
   };
```

And on where you do the positive use

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     mhandler.sendMessage(Message.obtain(mhandler, SCORE_UP));
     //score.setText("Your Score Is " + playerscore);
   }
});
```

Comment: That solved the timer problem, but changing the score still does not work. Could you help me with that problem also?

Comment: You are trying to update the UI from a thread. You create the Handler on your code but without the contents to manage the message and never are posting a message to it.

Comment: On this example, I have not run it, so don't know how it behaves. i think you may want to check on a "Serial Execution tasks", where you can trigger actions and will be executed in order. That could make your game a little more robust since, you will not get a fail before a win. or vice versa.

Comment: I fixed the button problem. Just if you were wondering I used a handler like you said and called the random number outside the if statement